# foreach php for dynamic menu css

Tags: php, html, foreach

I have represented here below a css menu.php with different levels of the ul li, which is called when I do a include.
[image]

and here your code:

```
<div class="cont_menu">
        <div class="menu">

        <ul>
        <li><a class="hide" href="#" style="font-weight:bold;">CATALOGO</a>

        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <a href="../menu/index.html">CATALOGO
        <table><tr><td>
        <![endif]-->

            <ul>
            <li><a href="udi_categoria.php?listar=cat_nivel&par=1&op=insert&nivel=1" title="Categorias de Produtos">CATEG. E PROD.</a></li>
            <li><a href="prod_sem_cat.php" title="PRODUTOS SEM CATEGORIA">PROD. S/ CAT.</a></li>
            <li><a href="udi_caracteristica.php?op=insert" title="Removing active/focus borders">CARACTERISTICA</a></li>

            <li><a class="hide" href="../menu/hover_click.html" title="Hover/click with no active/focus borders">HOVER/CLICK &gt;</a>

            <!--[if lte IE 6]>
            <a class="sub" href="../menu/hover_click.html" title="Hover/click with no active/focus borders">HOVER/CLICK &gt;
            <table><tr><td>
            <![endif]-->

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../menu/form.html" title="Styling forms">styled form</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../menu/nodots.html" title="Removing active/focus borders">active focus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../menu/hover_click.html" title="Hover/click with no active/focus borders">hover/click</a></li>
                </ul>

            <!--[if lte IE 6]>
            </td></tr></table>
            </a>
            <![endif]-->

            </li>

            <li><a href="udi_menu.php" title="Cadastro de Menu">MENU</a></li>
            <li><a href="udi_usuario.php?op=insert" title="Image Map for detailed information">USUARIOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="../menu/bodies.html" title="fun with background images">fun backgrounds</a></li>
            <li><a href="../menu/fade_scroll.html" title="fade-out scrolling">fade scrolling</a></li>
            <li><a href="../menu/em_images.html" title="em size images compared">em sized images</a></li>
            </ul>

        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        </td></tr></table>
        </a>
        <![endif]-->

        </li>

        <li><a class="hide" style="font-weight:bold;" href="index.html">MENUS</a>

        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <a href="index.html">MENUS
        <table><tr><td>
        <![endif]-->

            <ul>
            <li><a href="spies.html" title="a coded list of spies">spies menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="vertical.html" title="a horizontal vertical menu">vertical menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="expand.html" title="an enlarging unordered list">enlarging list</a></li>
            <li><a href="enlarge.html" title="an unordered list with link images">link images</a></li>
            <li><a href="cross.html" title="non-rectangular links">non-rectangular</a></li>
            <li><a href="jigsaw.html" title="jigsaw links">jigsaw links</a></li>
            <li><a href="circles.html" title="circular links">circular links</a></li>
            </ul>

        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        </td></tr></table>
        </a>
        <![endif]-->

        </li>

        <li><a style="font-weight:bold;" class="hide" href="../layouts/index.html">LAYOUTS</a>

        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <a href="../layouts/index.html">LAYOUTS
        <table><tr><td>
        <![endif]-->

            <ul>
            <li><a href="../layouts/bodyfix.html" title="Cross browser fixed layout">Fixed 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="../layouts/body2.html" title="Cross browser fixed layout">Fixed 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="../layouts/body4.html" title="Cross browser fixed layout">Fixed 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="../layouts/body5.html" title="Cross browser fixed layout">Fixed 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="../layouts/minimum.html" title="A simple minimum width layout">minimum width</a></li>
            </ul>

        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        </td></tr></table>
        </a>
        <![endif]-->

        </li>

        <li><a style="font-weight:bold;" class="hide" href="../boxes/index.html">BOXES</a>

        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <a href="../boxes/index.html">BOXES
        <table><tr><td>
        <![endif]-->

            <ul>
            <li><a href="spies.html" title="a coded list of spies">spies menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="vertical.html" title="a horizontal vertical menu">vertical menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="expand.html" title="an enlarging unordered list">enlarging list</a></li>
            <li><a href="enlarge.html" title="an unordered list with link images">link images</a></li>
            <li><a href="cross.html" title="non-rectangular links">non-rectangular</a></li>
            <li><a href="jigsaw.html" title="jigsaw links">jigsaw links</a></li>
            <li><a href="circles.html" title="circular links">circular links</a></li>
            </ul>

        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        </td></tr></table>
        </a>
        <![endif]-->

        </li>

        <li><a style="font-weight:bold;" class="hide" href="../mozilla/index.html">MOZILLA</a>

        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <a href="../mozilla/index.html">MOZILLA
        <table><tr><td>
        <![endif]-->

            <ul>
            <li><a href="../mozilla/dropdown.html" title="A drop down menu">drop down menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="../mozilla/cascade.html" title="A cascading menu">cascading menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="../mozilla/content.html" title="Using content:">content:</a></li>
            <li><a href="../mozilla/moxbox.html" title=":hover applied to a div">mozzie box</a></li>
            <li><a href="../mozilla/rainbow.html" title="I can build a rainbow">rainbow box</a></li>
            <li><a href="../mozilla/snooker.html" title="Snooker cue">snooker cue</a></li>
            <li><a href="../mozilla/target.html" title="Target Practise">target practise</a></li>
            <li><a href="../mozilla/splittext.html" title="Two tone headings">two tone headings</a></li>
            <li><a href="../mozilla/shadow_text.html" title="Shadow text">shadow text</a></li>
            </ul>

        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        </td></tr></table>
        </a>
        <![endif]-->

        </li>

        <li><a style="font-weight:bold;" class="hide" href="../ie/index.html">EXPLORER</a>

        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <a href="../ie/index.html">EXPLORER
        <table><tr><td>
        <![endif]-->

            <ul>
            <li><a href="../ie/exampleone.html" title="Example one">example one</a></li>
            <li><a href="../ie/weft.html" title="Weft fonts">weft fonts</a></li>
            <li><a href="../ie/exampletwo.html" title="Vertical align">vertical align</a></li>
            </ul>

        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        </td></tr></table>
        </a>
        <![endif]-->

        </li>

        <li><a style="font-weight:bold;" class="hide" href="../opacity/index.html">OPACITY</a>

        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <a href="../opacity/index.html">OPACITY
        <table><tr><td>
        <![endif]-->

            <ul>
            <li><a href="../opacity/colours.html" title="colour wheel">opaque colours</a></li>
            <li><a href="../opacity/picturemenu.html" title="a menu using opacity">opaque menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="../opacity/png.html" title="partial opacity">partial opacity</a></li>
            <li><a href="../opacity/png2.html" title="partial opacity II">partial opacity II</a></li>
            <li><a class="hide" href="../menu/hover_click.html" title="Hover/click with no active/focus borders">&lt; HOVER/CLICK</a>

            <!--[if lte IE 6]>
            <a class="sub" href="../menu/hover_click.html" title="Hover/click with no active/focus borders">&lt; HOVER/CLICK
            <table><tr><td>
            <![endif]-->

                <ul class="left">
                    <li><a href="../menu/form.html" title="Styling forms">styled form</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../menu/nodots.html" title="Removing active/focus borders">active focus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../menu/hover_click.html" title="Hover/click with no active/focus borders">hover/click</a></li>
                </ul>

            <!--[if lte IE 6]>
            </td></tr></table>
            </a>
            <![endif]-->

            </li>
            </ul>

        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        </td></tr></table>
        </a>
        <![endif]-->

        </li>
        </ul>

        </div>


    </div>
```

the menu has to be dynamic, each User has delegated pages for me, I made these tables in the database to store the menu:

[image]

[image]

so i do this select:

```
$p = new DB();
$p->setSQLcommand("SELECT menu_descr,sup_cod,level,menu_link,menu_title
                    FROM acesso
                    WHERE access_id in (SELECT access_id as id
                            FROM cpd_colaborador_acesso
                            WHERE col_cod = ".$_SESSION["colaborador"].")");                    
$t = $p->ExecSelect();
```

Here I show you a var_dump to the result

```
array
 0 => 
   array
    'menu_descr' => string 'CATALOGO' (length=8)
    0 => string 'CATALOGO' (length=8)
    'sup_cod' => null
    1 => null
    'level' => string '1' (length=1)
    2 => string '1' (length=1)
    'menu_link' => string '#' (length=1)
    3 => string '#' (length=1)
    'menu_title' => string 'CATALOGO' (length=8)
    4 => string 'CATALOGO' (length=8)
1 => 
  array
    'menu_descr' => string 'CATEG. E PROD.' (length=14)
    0 => string 'CATEG. E PROD.' (length=14)
    'sup_cod' => string '15' (length=2)
    1 => string '15' (length=2)
    'level' => string '2' (length=1)
    2 => string '2' (length=1)
    'menu_link' => string 'http://localhost/compararprecosde/admin 
     /udi_categoria.php?listar=cat_nivel&par=1&op=insert&nivel=1' (length=98)
    3 => string 'http://localhost/compararprecosde/admin
    /udi_categoria.php?listar=cat_nivel&par=1&op=insert&nivel=1' (length=98)
    'menu_title' => string 'Categoria e Produtos' (length=20)
    4 => string 'Categoria e Produtos' (length=20)
2 => 
  array
    'menu_descr' => string 'PROD. S/ CAT.' (length=13)
    0 => string 'PROD. S/ CAT.' (length=13)
    'sup_cod' => string '15' (length=2)
    1 => string '15' (length=2)
    'level' => string '2' (length=1)
    2 => string '2' (length=1)
    'menu_link' => string 'http://localhost/compararprecosde/admin/prod_sem_cat.php'   
    (length=56)
    3 => string 'http://localhost/compararprecosde/admin/prod_sem_cat.php' (length=56)
    'menu_title' => string 'Produtos sem Categoria' (length=22)
    4 => string 'Produtos sem Categoria' (length=22)
```

Now's the question I would like to integrate the array of results with ul and li in a foreach () php, considering it's title in first place and that is level 1, and it's subcategories, I have no idea how this can be represented in logic programming...

Thank you all..

Comment: Not sure why this asker got a downvote... seems like a clear and valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may need some tweaking as I don't have a PHP server available at the moment. I hope it's at least close to what you need.

```
<?php
$lastLevel = 0;

foreach($t as $entry)
{
    if($entry['level'] > $lastLevel)
    {
        $lastLevel = $entry['level'];
        echo "<ul>";
    }
    else if($entry['level'] < $lastLevel)
    {
        $lastLevel = $entry['level'];
        echo "</li></ul>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "</li>";
    }

    echo "<li><a href='" . $entry['menu_link'] . "'>" . $entry['menu_title'] . "</a>";
}

for($x = $lastLevel; $x > 0; $x--)
{
    echo "</li></ul>";
}
?>
```